# Cannot install martinlindhe/laravel-vue-i18n-generator with Laravel 8

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vue-i18n

I try to install `martinlindhe/laravel-vue-i18n-generator` with `Laravel 8` and it show the error:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It says **'This repository has been archived by the owner. It is now read-only.'** So it is archived and that means it won't be developed. Since Laravel  8 is never than this package (last commit was like 2 years ago for this package).

Try to look Laravel's default language solution or [found this package](https://github.com/richan-fongdasen/laravel-i18n)

Comment: Thanks you for your help, I follow the link and I see it focus on translate content from db. And my purpose is translate the the Label only

Comment: Just use Laravel's translate. Not a package then.

Answer (score 0):

Try to look at [vue-i18n-extract](https://github.com/Spittal/vue-i18n-extract)